# Why word "weighten" aren't actually a valid word?

Tags: derivational-morphology, word-formation

There's bunch of words with `-en` form of word like `height`-`heighten`, `bright`-`brighten` and others, but `weight`-`weighten` aren't valid pair. Is there any reasons, why is it like that? Is there any rule for that kind of morphology?

Comment: English is a living language; it evolves. Wiktionary actually lists 'weighten', but I'd wait until it's known whether OED has accepted it before claiming it as a word. It may have been slow in becoming accepted (assuming it _is_ accepted) because 'weight' is already used as a verb. No doubt someone will soon ask "Why has 'weighten' been accepted as a word when the verb 'weight' is already in use?"

Comment: You say: "Is there any consistent rule for that kind of morphology?". It may help you to know that there are no consistent rules in English. :) **Sight - to sighten**; and **fight - to fighten** do not work either.

Comment: @Greybeard yeah, you're right, updated question a bit about consistensy.

Comment: @Greybeard `fight` is verb i.e. some action, and `sight` is noun for some "action ability", but height, brightness and weight are properties someone can "enlarge" in a sense. So I basically speak about that kind property words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These "gh" spellings have germanic roots and come down to us from our Anglo-Saxon heritage.  A common conversion from noun to verb is to add *-en*.  so we have *long*, *length* and *lengthen* (make longer); *strong*, *strength* and *strengthen*; *fear*, *fright* and *frighten*.  And so on.  As Edwin Ashworth says, that does not mean that all such possibilities have been used.  But many have:  *cheap* to *cheapen*; *stiff* to *stiffen*; *straight* to *straighten*.  Some just have not caught on, probably because not really needed.  The verb *weigh*, for example, is already a verb, so why would we need a verb meaning *make heavier*?  We often want to make things lighter, and, lo and behold, we have the verb *lighten*.  The only non-germanic word that allows this treatment is *to christen*.  Otherwise, stick to the Anglo-Saxon monosyllables.

If you really feel you need a verb for making something heavier, other than *weight it down (more)*.  There already exists the verb *to weight*.

If you think that the right word does not exist for you, you can coin a neologism, provided you are sure its meaning will be obvious enough, and signal what you are doing by placing it within single inverted commas.

Comment: *The verb weigh, for example, is already a verb, so why would we need a verb meaning make heavier?* We have one: "I weighted the sack with stones to serve as an anchor."

Comment: @Greybeard Just so.

Comment: @Greybeard I suspect it's also something to do with the other words available for the same idea (*burden*, *emburden*, *encumber* etc etc).